# SQL getting date ranges from this month and last month only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to pull data from this month and last month only but I'm getting a bit confused when dates span across a year.
For example, my initial query was simply pulling data from `Month(getdate()) and Month(getdate())-1` which worked fine during the year, but, as today is 2nd Jan 2020, my query isn't returning anything for Dec 2019 (as obviously, `Month(getdate())-1` equals zero).

I've now changed my where clause to...

```
where Month(InstrDate) in  (MONTH(getDate()),Month(DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()))) 
and year(InstrDate) in  (year(getDate()),year(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, getdate())))
```

...this now works fine for this month but I'm wondering what will happen next month when 'this month' and 'last month' are within the same year.

I think the `where` clause will be ok as it will return (for example) Feb and Jan for this year and last year(?) but I think my case statement will not work as it will include both years...

```
case 
when month(Instrdate) = Month(getdate()) and year(Instrdate) = year(getdate()) then 'This Month'
when month(Instrdate) = Month(DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())) and year(Instrdate) = year(DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()))then 'Last Month'
end as 'Month',
```

Surely my 'Last Month' line will always return the previous month from last year....how can I ensure that it always returns the month previous to the current month?

Update: The Database is SQL 2008 - therefore EOMONTH not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you're after is this:

```
WHERE YourDateColumn < DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
  AND YourDateColumn >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2))
```

For today, that would give you all rows **before** `2020-02-01` and **on or after** `2019-12-01`.

Edit: You should avoid expressions like `MONTH(YourDateColumn) = MONTH(GETDATE())` in the `WHERE` as well. Doing so creates a non-SARGable query, so any indexes will be useless to the RDBMS, because of the use of the `MONTH` function on the column. Stick to *"proper"* date logic.

---

As the OP has now advised they are using an **unsupported** version of SQL Server, then won't be able to use `EOMONTH`. You can, however, use the `DATEADD` technique:

```
WHERE YourDateColumn < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+1,0)
  AND YourDateColumn >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1,0)
```

Comment: I think the SQL server must be older than 2012 as I'm getting 'EOMONTH not a recognized function' (I'll update the question).

Comment: It is **strongly** *assumed* that you are using a supported software when you ask a question, @dazzathedrummer . If you aren't, you should be warning people, and tagging the unsupported software.

Comment: Yes, apologies, it's not a database that I work on regularly and it will soon be in run-off. I only spotted the version problem when I tried to run EOMONTH.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a solution for older, unsupported versions of SQL Server, @dazzathedrummer . Ideally, however, you should really be looking at upgrade paths ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get data from the previous month is:

```
where datediff(month, Instrdate, getdate()) = 1
```

That is, there is one month boundary between the date and the current date.

The downside to this approach is that it cannot use an index on `Instrdate`.  That is, it is not *sargable*.

Another method is:

```
where instrdate < convert(date, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate())) and
      instrdate >= dateadd(month, -1, convert(date, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate())))
```